# Bypass pg_scape_string in SQL INjection

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, sql-injection

Can i bypass the pg_scape_string to do a SQl Inject atack?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! You'd need to be more specific on what help you require. What are you trying to inject?

Answer (score 0):

i need to bypass the pg_scape_string, for example: 
In a code with pg_scape_string

```
$sql = pg_scape_string("select * from tableusers where username ='".$_POST['user']."'"); 

With the input: 0' or 0=0 --
```

The SQL in the database will be "select * from tableusers where username = ''0 or 0=0 -- '"
the quotes were duplicated, i need bypass this sanitize and do with that quotes not be duplicated.